Understanding how entanglement physically arises in nature
My background is in CS and I have just started to learn Quantum Computing. From what I have understood: Given a set of $N$ qbits that are in some superposition state, can entangle these qbits with another set of $M$ qbits that are in $|0000... \rangle$ state using quantum gate operations (please correct me if I am wrong). So, in QC we take a set of quantum bits and do an intentional quantum operation on them such that we achieve a desired quantum state (superposition, entanglement etc).
Query 1: Now, my Question is from physics perspective. Lets take $N$ qbits in a superposition state (mentioned above) and another set of $M$ qbits in ground (all 0 state as mentioned above) and put them inside a physical container. Let us assume that they do not interact with the container/environment at all.
Do these qbits system become entangled spontaneously (without any gate operations) or do we always need to have some gate operations to create an entangled state?
Query 2: If they spontaneously become entangled how does that happen physically without quantum gates? And what does the final entangles state looks like i.e. can we explicitly write down the final state if we know the initial state (just as in quantum gate operations)?
I am terribly confused but I really want to understand how entanglement arises in nature and not just using quantum gates. Please provide a conceptual idea as my background is not in physics.
Note: Most texts I read either talk about creating an entangled state or via gates (logical setup) or the creating of entangled pair using a physical process of emission of 2 photons from a particle. The above question is fundamentally different.

I think, this depends on what kind of physical realization of qubits you consider. In general, physical systems get more and more entangled, but this entanglement does not lead to interference because of decoherence. But there are processes in nature, where entangled particles are created naturally. For example in subatomic particle decays.

thanks but whatever little i read about entanglement it is a fundamental physical phenomenon - for both matter and photons. so i am unsure if entanglement will depend   on the type of matter particles. and i read a little about creation of entangled photons (SPDC) or particle decay. But my question is fundamentally different. We have a set of particles in a super position state and another in ground state. We have not created them and don't care about the source. How do they get entangled and their final state is determined (we are Not creating them).

It's a mathematical fact, inherent in the mathematical structure of the Quantum theoretical framework, that when you go above ~4/5 qubits of information, the vast majority of possible states of your system are entangled ones. So apart from that statistical argument, how exactly such random entangled states arise, I don't think we really know, because we weren't the ones that created them ;) but perhaps someone can elaborate on that and give a more detailed answer.

@Amit thanks but I am totally lost on above comment. I think you are assuming I know a lot of background (but I don't). My questions (at least I think so :)) are self contained but I can't find a clear answer to either one. Gates operate on particles to give a clear superposition/entangled state but what happens In a container? How does entangled state arise physically without any gates? Given the initial superposition and ground states pair can we calculate the resultant entangled state in container?

A "gate" is an abstraction useful in computer science for time evolution with some Hamiltonian operator. Anything you think of as a "gate" can be reduced down to a physical layer and described in terms of interactions between particles and fields. And, any evolution described the physical layer can be packaged and abstracted into a "gate." So for Q1, I would say you are making a distinction without a difference, you can describe the process in terms of gates or in terms of physical interactions, but either way particles can become entangled when they interact.

@stack.tarandeep As an analogy only: If you flip a $100$ coins on a table, in the vast majority of cases they are not going to turn out either all heads or all tails. To be precise in $2^{100}-2$ out of $2^{100}$ of the times, they won't. I was trying to say that we don't really have a deep knowledge AFAIK of what causes entanglement naturally, apart from knowing the analogous thing to the $100$ coins case: the vast majority of states are simply entangled ones, relatively very few aren't. So all systems that are allowed to evolve naturally, are likely to be entangled.

@stack.tarandeep To be a bit more on the point with regards to QC: the real issue there is the random entanglement of the qubits with the environment, rather than with one another. This is known as Quantum decoherence

If particles A and B are maximally entangled, then neither can be entangled to any particle C. This is called monogamy of entanglement.
Distributed Entanglement: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907047
Therefore: If there are 3 or more entangled particles, their entanglement cannot be maximal. How would we characterize the relationship between their observables on some basis? You can’t - unless you know something about their overall state, and that itself requires some kind of superposition.
So whenever you have N>2 particles collected “naturally”, you can’t make any meaningful statement (ie based on observation) about them being entangled. If there is some degree of entanglement, then it definitely will be less than maximal. Accordingly there is no specific relationship to be measured, and you cannot conclude there is entanglement present. It’s an empty statement.
There are N>2 states such as |GHZ> and |W> which can be identified by a suitably large sample of full measurements. But generally these cannot be created by simply bringing particles together. They are created by specific operations to build them up, usually using maximally entangled pairs as building blocks.
So I would not agree that most particles are entangled, certainly not in any manner that can be demonstrated objectively. It would just be an assumption, and not maximal.
A side note: it is possible to verifiably create maximally entangled pairs from independent sources. At the base of such process, however, there is an operation which is definitely not “natural”.

Answer 1: If a non-interacting quantum state $\mathbb\Psi$ factors at time $t$ (e.g. when it is initialized), quantum theory predicts that (absent wave function collapse) it will factor at all future times.  This is basically a result of the action of the (non-interacting) time evolution operator on tensor products: $U(t)\mathbb \Psi = U_1(t)\psi_1\otimes U_2(t)\psi_2\otimes U_3(t)\psi_3\otimes \dots$.  Hence, some kind of interaction (or correlated operator in the Hamiltonian) is necessary to introduce entanglement.  In quantum gates, this interaction is embedded in "control" elements/terminals.
Answer 2: According to the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics, entanglement can also be introduced "instantaneously" if a non-entangled wave function is measured from an "entangled" basis set (i.e. if you measure an observable whose eigenstates are entangled.) However, this is not a reliable way of introducing entanglement, in part because quantum measurement is hard to control experimentally: you can control the conditions under which a measurement or series of measurements occurs, and you can control where "measurement products" are funneled (e.g. with something like a Stern Gerlach apparatus), but you can't control when measurement occurs (except by adjusting the flux/rate of a process.)  Essentially, this "measurement" process occurs semi-continuously throughout an experiment, and would be a significant source of decoherence at ultra-low temperatures.  Controlling the process of wave function collapse would essentially be equivalent to controlling decoherence.
In non-relativistic QM, most entanglement is introduced by interaction terms in the Hamiltonian that are rapidly "turned on" and/or subsequently "turned off", so that the Born-Oppenheimer approximation doesn't apply (when the Hamiltonian changes slowly rather than rapidly, eigenstates transform to eigenstates, and "most" natural/non-irradiated measurements take place during transitions between eigenstates involving photon emission/absorption.) Otherwise, entanglement can be thought of as "existing" in the ground states of strongly interacting systems, but this sort of entanglement is harder to "observe" in a tangible sense, and from a certain perspective can be thought of as an artifact of a particular theoretical description (i.e. describing the exact ground state of an interacting system in terms of non-interacting free-particle states): that being said, such "theoretical artifacts" can be incidental to guiding/shaping the design of quantum technologies.

So, as TLDR explained, you need interactions to produce entanglement. Let's consider a bunch of particles in a physical contain, initially in some separable state $|a\rangle|b\rangle ... |n\rangle$. That means that each particle has a specific state representing its momentum and position.
Now we allow them to collide (interaction elastically). Although the initial conditions for two colliding particles are fixed, the final conditions are not because the process is under constrained. There are many possible momenta that the two particles can have after the collision while still maintaining momentum and energy conservation. Based on quantum mechanics, these two particle will thus end up in a superposition of all such possibilities.
$$ |a\rangle|b\rangle \rightarrow  |c\rangle|d\rangle + |e\rangle|f\rangle + ... $$
Such a superposition is an entangled state because it cannot be factorized. These collisions can happen between any two particles, so you can imagine how complicated the collective state eventually becomes.
The OP question asked about "qubits" and not "particles." So then it depends on how these qubits are represented physically when they are placed in a physical container. The state of a qubit is much simpler (lives on a smaller Hilbert space) than that of a particle. So I'm not sure how to come up with a physical system that would represent such a situation.
